# liferay resource within included javascript file

Tags: jquery, ajax, liferay, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

when i use this :

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="ajaxURL" id="ajax" escapeXml="false" />


 $.ajax({
    method : "POST",
        url : "${ajaxURL}",
        data : {
    ...
```

inside my ajax call that is not included in page it works.

but when i try to include that same javscript code on page i get error:

```
WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-27][404_jsp:109] /$%7BajaxURL%7D
```

My question is how to pass that resource url to included javascript or how to generate it within javascript.

i have tried:
`var urlVar = '<portlet:resourceURL var="ajaxURL" id="ajax" escapeXml="false" />'`

and when i use urlVar on this way:

```
$.ajax({
method : "POST",
    url : urlVar,
    data : {
...
```

It doesnt works. Does anyone knows how to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Assuming it is a jsp page try url : "<%=ajaxURL%>"

Comment: i guess you can do it directly as well.i.e 
 url : '<portlet:resourceURL var="ajaxURL" id="ajax"/> ',

Comment: i tested both propositions and they do not work unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. One way doing this is to define resource url on jsp page for example like this:

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="yourResourceURL" id="yourResource" />
```

and to pass it from jsp within paramter to the function that is located in external js file.

for example in js:

```
function test(urlVar) {
    alert(urlVar);
        $.ajax({
            method : "POST",
            url : urlVar,
            success : function(data) {

            }
        });
}
```

and in jsp call that function like this:

```
 test(" ${yourResourceURL} ");
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate resourceURL using java script

```
var resourceURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createResourceURL();
resourceURL.setPortletId(86);
resourceURL .setParameter("key2", "value");
resourceURL.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options for you.

To use JSP tags and EL in a JavaScript file, you will need to serve it from a JSP. I've done this in portlets before by using the `serveResource` method to serve the JavaScript file. This way you can use the same portlet tags in your JavaScript JSP.

In your portlet JSP

```
<portlet:resourceURL var='portletJS' id='javascriptResourceID' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='${portletJS'></script>
```

In your portlet's `serveResource` method.

```
if (request.getResourceID == "javascriptResourceID) {
    //render JSP for JavaScript
}
```

The other option is to set a JavaScript variable in your portlet and then use that variable in your static JavaScript file.

In your portlet JSP

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var portletAjaxURL = '<portlet:resourceURL id="ajax" escapeXml="false" />';
</script>
```

In your static JavaScript file

```
$.ajax({
    method : "POST",
    url : portletAjaxURL,
    data : {
    ...
```

Comment: i haven't yet tested 1st method, but second won't work because of javascript variable scope range. Because if you declare portletAjaxUrl in script tags, and later on you import other javascript code behind those tags, it will not be able to consume that variable.

Comment: JavaScript variables aren't confined to the <script> tag or JavaScript file that they are declared. In the <script> tag, that variable declaration puts the variable in the global scope, making it available everywhere else on the page, or in other JS files or tags.

Comment: can you post complete working example? i can't get this to work.